# What is + - # and empty prefix in laravel dump objects and what does that empty prefix mean?

Tags: php, laravel, object

I inspected Carbon date instance in laravel by dd function and i found there is + - # and empty prefix and i did not understand what is empty prefix means ? How to implement exactly same in php class ?

Creating php objects with private, public and protected property i only get -,+,# symbols but i could not figure out how to get without prefix

[image: object dump]

Comment: `-` means private property, `#` means protected property (there is honestly no plus, `+05:45` is just the time ahead of you), and public properties do not have `+`... It is a simple as just creating a class with a protect, a private, and a public property, do a `dd` and see what prints out....

Comment: it's just visual for you to differentiate the attributes nature when you dump an object. What is exactly your question ?

Comment: I was asking what is date property without any symbol and how could i replicate same type of property on my own class ? Did you understand N69S ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty prefix (purple color) represents metadata.

The `dump()` function (Symfony's `VarDumper Component`) uses `Caster` classes to convert the object that needs to be dumped to output.

If the object is an instance of a commonly used class (e.g. a built-in php class, a Symfony or Doctrine class), a custom `Caster` class is used that may add additional data to the dumped output, or hide data to make the output easier to read (e.g. filter out Doctrine internals while dumping a single proxy entity).

For a `DateTime` instance (`Carbon` extends `DateTime`), the `DateCaster` class is used, which adds the `date` key with a formatted representation of the `DateTime` object: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Caster/DateCaster.php

So you cannot simply add properties without a prefix `+#-` yourself, unless you write your own `Caster`:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/advanced.html#casters